# "not a function" error when referencing jquery library in ASP.NET MVC View with Telerik MVC Extensions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

In the script below, the .cluetip() function call results in "$(".tip").cluetip is not a function".  I'm certain that the library is properly referenced b/c I can follow the link from the source.  Also, the .click() function works fine.  What am I missing?  Many thanks!

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cluetip.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".tip").click(function () { alert('hi mom!'); }); // this works
        $(".tip").cluetip(); // results in $(".tip").cluetip is not a function
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the position of jquery.cluetip.js higher, right after where you insert the jquery library?

Comment: @Niklas - thanks - good suggestion, but id didn't seem to help.  This is the first time I've tried cluetip.  I'll keep poking around at it.  -- must

Comment: it really should work as you have in your example. Only thing that crossed my mind is that if some other javascript breaks it on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a jQuery conflict.  The Telerik MVC extension templates automatically add the following line to _layout.cshtml:

```
 @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
        .DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true))
```

At the time of this writing, this statement will add jQuery version 1.5.1.  By default, jQuery is also included at the top of the _layout.cshtml file:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hence, a conflict.

**Solution**

The way I solved this was to include jQuery version 1.5.1 in the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then suppress the jQuery output from Telerik:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
    .DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true))
    .jQuery(false))
```